# Multiple error cases for single OSStatus iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to delete keys from Secure Enclave on iOS in Swift. I continuously get [OSStatus response -50](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50). From what I can tell from the link there are 22 errors associated with OSStatus -50 for `SecBasePrivate.h`. How can I get more detailed error info or a specific error name?

```
var query : [String: Any] = [
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
    kSecAttrLabel as String: keychainTagPublic,
]
var status = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `SecItemDelete` status results, we should probably be looking in the *SecBase.h* header:

```
errSecParam = -50, /* One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. */
```

Comment: My guess is that you need CFString keys but that is _just_ a guess.

Comment: Ah ok. So from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1395547-secitemdelete) how can I tell which `.h` file I should be looking for? Neither SecBasePrivate nor SecBase are mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you can tell that from the documentation. The documentation doesn't show values of these sorts of constants.